# "Не значащий" или "незначащий"?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Как правильно:
*Мы обменялись ничего не значащими фразами.*
или
*Мы обменялись ничего незначащими фразами.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Мы обменялись ничего не значащими фразами.* Они ничего *не значили*. Видите, что отрицание есть? Значит, раздельно.

*Мы обменялись незначащими фразами*. А здесь отрицания нет. Малозначащими фразами обменялись. Слитно.

Answer (score 5):

Существует простое и понятное правило: если слову с частицей НЕ предшествует отрицательное местоимение или наречие, то частица НЕ пишется с  этим словом раздельно. Здесь как раз такой случай